# How to translate make_pair in c++ to c#?

Tags: c#, c++

```
map <pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int> kmapValues;
```

with

```
private Dictionary<KeyValuePair<uint, uint>, uint> kmapValues;
```

replace

```
kmapValues[make_pair(j, i)] = 1
```

with

```
kmapValues[Tuple(j, i)] = 1 // got error
```

> System.Tuple is type but used like a variable error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring a dictionary to use `KeyValuePair<K,V>` keys, but you are trying to access it with `Tuple<T1,T2>` instead. You need to decide on one type, and stay with it.

Since `KeyValuePair<K,V>` is asymmetric, I would use `Tuple<T1,T2>`:

```
private Dictionary<Tuple<uint, uint>, uint> kmapValues;
```

Then your assignment would work correctly:

```
kmapValues[Tuple.Create(j, i)] = 1;
```

Comment: Actually you need `Tuple.Create`, which is as close to a `make_pair` equivalent as there is in C#. Or `new Tuple<uint, uint>(...)`, but that's unwieldy.

Comment: @Jon Great suggestion, thank you very much! `Tuple.Create` is indeed much closer to `make_pair` of C++.

Comment: can not create an instance of static class "System.Tuple" after compile

Comment: @HoYeungLee Please take a look at the edit. I was missing a pair of type names before.

Answer (score 2):

// As a C# extension method, on some static class:

```
public static KeyValuePair<K, V> MakePair<K, V>(this K k, V v) { return new KeyValuePair<K, V>(k, v); }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to refactor to use a vector to then map near the C# Interface, then the wrapper function returns sub elements by reference, you can then re-compose as needed; it's a bit more work, but worth it in my opinion.

An example from a recent project:
As you see, theere's a lot of function calls here, but still fairly straightforward.

```
    public struct InputLinkOutputProbeGeneratedInfoSimple
    {
        public bool HasValidVisualRGBSettings;
        public int VisualRGB_resX0;
        public int VisualRGB_resY0;
        public IlVisualGenPlane VisualRGB_iteratorPlaneMode;
        public ulong VisualRGB_startX;
        public ulong VisualRGB_startY;
        public Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int> TextureXYToProbeIndex_Red;
        public Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int> TextureXYToProbeIndex_Green;
        public Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int> TextureXYToProbeIndex_Blue;
    }

     [DllImport("EDeNServerInterfaceDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Count", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private extern static int GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Count();
    //-----
    [DllImport("EDeNServerInterfaceDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Red", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private extern static void GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Red(int idx, out int x, out int y, out int inLnkIdx);
    //-----
    [DllImport("EDeNServerInterfaceDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Green", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private extern static void GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Green(int idx, out int x, out int y, out int inLnkIdx);
    //-----
    [DllImport("EDeNServerInterfaceDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Blue", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private extern static void GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Blue(int idx, out int x, out int y, out int inLnkIdx);
    public static InputLinkOutputProbeGeneratedInfoSimple GetCurrentInputLinkOutputProbeGeneratedInfoSimple()
    {
        InputLinkOutputProbeGeneratedInfoSimple ilopgis = new InputLinkOutputProbeGeneratedInfoSimple();
        //
        ilopgis.HasValidVisualRGBSettings = GetCurrentInputLinkOutputProbeGeneratedInfo_HasValidVisualRGBSettings();
        ilopgis.VisualRGB_resX0 = GetCurrentInputLinkOutputProbeGeneratedInfo_VisualRGB_resX();
        ilopgis.VisualRGB_resY0 = GetCurrentInputLinkOutputProbeGeneratedInfo_VisualRGB_resY();
        ilopgis.VisualRGB_iteratorPlaneMode = GetCurrentInputLinkOutputProbeGeneratedInfo_VisualRGB_iteratorPlaneMode();
        ilopgis.VisualRGB_startX = GetCurrentInputLinkOutputProbeGeneratedInfo_VisualRGB_startX();
        ilopgis.VisualRGB_startY = GetCurrentInputLinkOutputProbeGeneratedInfo_VisualRGB_startY();
        ilopgis.TextureXYToProbeIndex_Red = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>();
        ilopgis.TextureXYToProbeIndex_Green = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>();
        ilopgis.TextureXYToProbeIndex_Blue = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>();

        int x = 0, y = 0, inLnkIdx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Count(); i++)
        {
            //
            GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Red(i, out x, out y, out inLnkIdx);
            ilopgis.TextureXYToProbeIndex_Red[new Tuple<int, int>(x, y)] = inLnkIdx;
            //
            GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Green(i, out x, out y, out inLnkIdx);
            ilopgis.TextureXYToProbeIndex_Green[new Tuple<int, int>(x, y)] = inLnkIdx;
            //
            GetCurrentTextureXYToProbeIndex_Blue(i, out x, out y, out inLnkIdx);
            ilopgis.TextureXYToProbeIndex_Blue[new Tuple<int, int>(x, y)] = inLnkIdx;
        }
        //
        return ilopgis;
    }
```